# Double click on a web link results in visiting the link in the default browser

Tags: url, web-browser

Assume that in the current buffer there is some text like `http://emacs.stackexchange.com/`. Is it possible to customize Emacs so that double clicking on this text, results in visiting the link by the deafult browser? (i.e., like hyperref in LaTeX).

Comment: Is using mouse mandatory?  `M-x ffap`, with point on the link, does what you want. You can bind `ffap` to double click with `(global-set-key [double-mouse-1] 'ffap)`.

Comment: @giordano Thank you very much. Please feel free to put your comment as an answer in order that I can acknowledge your help within site.

Comment: Please do some basic background research before posting.  A [google search for "emacs web link"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=emacs+web+link) turns up the [EmacsWiki page for `browse-url`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseUrl) and the [Emacs manual on external links](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/External-links.html) from `org-mode` as the first two hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `ffap` <kbd>RET</kbd> does what you want (will be requested a confirmation though).  You can bind it to double mouse click with

```
(global-set-key [double-mouse-1] 'ffap)
```

As the name suggests, `ffap` finds files at point, not just URLs.  If you want a function tailored to URLs look at the builtin `browse-url` package (as [suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6086/double-click-on-a-web-link-results-in-visiting-the-link-in-the-default-browser/6088?noredirect=1#comment9316_6086) by Dan), which also lets you choose the browser to use.  If you prefer `browse-url`, replace `ffap` with `browse-url` (or `browse-url-at-point` if you don't want to be prompted for confirmation, [thanks glucas](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6086/double-click-on-a-web-link-results-in-visiting-the-link-in-the-default-browser/6088?noredirect=1#comment9348_6088)!)  in the previous code to bind it to double click event.

Comment: Use `browse-url-at-point` if you don't want a confirmation prompt.

Comment: @glucas Thank you for your very useful comment.

Comment: But with `browse-url-at-point` double-clicking any string opens the browser. How can I limit Emacs to only browse actual URL's?