# Switch buffer to the file path in current cursor position

Tags: files, find-file

My .emacs file contains multiple file names as,

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/others/keymaps.el")
(load "~/.emacs.d/others/py.el")
(load "~/.emacs.d/others/web.el")
```

Is there a way any library, gives way for me to keep the cursor in the middle of file path and jump straight to the file content on pressing a shortcut.

`(load "~/.emacs.d/others`!!(cursor here)`/py.el")`

When the line cursor is in the middle of a file path, it must switch buffer to `~/.emacs.d/others/py.el`

Comment: I learned `(global-set-key [double-mouse-1] 'ffap)` here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6088/. Instead of `double-mouse-1` you can use your favorite shortcut. If this helps you, be sure to upvote the answer provided in that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(defun visit-file-at-point ()
  "Visit file at point if it exists."
  (interactive)
  (let ((file (ffap-guess-file-name-at-point)))
    (when file
      (find-file file))))
```

If you don't mind one additional key-stoke, you can use built-in
`find-file-at-point` command too.

Answer (score 6):

### For `ido` users

Add the below to your config and then `C-x C-f` (which should be executing `ido-find-file` automatically with `ido-mode` enabled) on such file paths will open those files directly.

```
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess)
```

### For `ivy`/[`counsel`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/counsel.el) users

Add the below to your config and then `M-x counsel-find-file` (which you can conveniently bind to `C-x C-f`)  on such file paths will open those files directly.

```
(setq counsel-find-file-at-point t)
```

Comment: Pressing `M-n` also works for ido, ivy, and the default completion, even without the find-at-point customization.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then **`M-.`** *always* [yanks the thing at point](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Inserting_Text_from_Cursor) into the minibuffer.

This is just one use case of that, where you yank the file name at point.

One key to remember (or not -- `M-?` provides help).